# Facing Error Message when trying to send email notification to multiple people Using AWS Lambda, SNS, S3, SES

Tags: python, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I want to design a system using AWS Lambda, S3, SNS, SES for an educational institution. In which whenever a subject teacher uploads her subject assignment in S3 bucket for a specific class and section then the email notification regarding the assignment uploading should be send automatically to Institution director, subject teacher, all students of that class and section as well as to the parents of all the students of that class and section. The notification email should also has the uploaded assignment as an attachment.

```
        For this I have two Lambda Functions, one is 'assignmentupload' Lambda Function and other is 'assignmentnotification' Lambda Function. When teacher uploads assignment in S3 bucket then it will trigger the 'assignment' upload Lambda Function and SNS topic will be used as the destination for this function. This SNS topic will trigger the second Lambda Function 'assignmentnotification' and this function will send the email notification having uploaded assignment as an attachment  to every person as describe earlier. 

       When I test this system by uploading a assignment file. Let the name of of assignment file is  'Maths_10_A_mathsassignment' I am getting the following two errors again and again.
```

[ERROR] KeyError: 'key'

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/var/task/assignmentnotificationlambda.py", line 18, in lambda_handler

```
parts = message['key'].split('_')  # Split the filename using underscores
```

The other Error is : Error sending email: name 'class_section' is not defined

```
My 'assignmentupload' Lambda Function python code is 


import boto3
import json

# Initialize the S3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
sns = boto3.client('sns')

# Replace 'your-sns-topic-arn' with your actual SNS topic ARN
SNS_TOPIC_ARN = 'paste your topic arn here'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        # Specify the S3 bucket name where assignments are uploaded
        s3_bucket = 'bucket_name'  # S3 bucket name where teachers will upload assignments

        # Extract S3 object information from the event
        s3_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

        # Extract assignment details from the S3 object key
        parts = s3_key.split('_')   # Split the filename using underscores
        subject = parts[0]  # The first part is the subject
        class_section = parts[1]  # The second part is the class_section

        # Construct the SNS message
        sns_message = {
            'key': 'Maths_10_A_mathsassignment.pdf',
            'subject': 'Maths',
            'class_section': '10_A',
            'bucket': 'bucket_name3',  # Include the 'bucket' key
        }

        # Publish the SNS message to trigger the assignmentnotification Lambda
        sns.publish(
            TopicArn=SNS_TOPIC_ARN,
            Message=json.dumps(sns_message)
        )

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(f'Assignment uploaded: {subject}, {class_section}')
        }

    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps(str(e))
        }



My 'assignmentnotification' Lambda Function python code is 

import boto3
import json
import os

ses = boto3.client('ses')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Load the email address mapping from a JSON file
EMAIL_MAPPING_FILE = 'email_mapping.json'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Load the email address mapping
    email_mapping = load_email_mapping()

    message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])

    # Extract assignment details from the S3 object key
    parts = message['key'].split('_')  # Split the filename using underscores
    subject = parts[0]  # The first part is the subject
    class_section = parts[1]  # The second part is the class_section

    # Construct the email subject
    email_subject = f"New Assignment: {subject} - {class_section}"

    # Construct the default email message
    email_message = f"Dear students and parents,\n\nPlease find the assignment attached."
    subject_line = f"New Assignment: {email_subject}"

    # Batch the recipients and send emails in batches
    recipients = email_mapping['principals'] + [get_subject_teacher_email(subject)]
    for student_email in email_mapping['students']:
        student_info = email_mapping['students'][student_email]
        recipients.append(student_email)
        recipients.append(student_info['parent_email'])

    # Send emails in batches of up to 50 recipients
    for i in range(0, len(recipients), 50):
        batch_recipients = recipients[i:i + 50]
        send_batch_email(batch_recipients, subject_line, email_message, message['bucket'], message['key'])

def load_email_mapping():
    s3_bucket = 'emaillistbucket'  # Specify the S3 bucket where email_mapping.json is stored
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=EMAIL_MAPPING_FILE)
    return json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))

def send_batch_email(recipients, subject, message, bucket, key):
    try:
        response = ses.send_email(
            Source='abc@xyz.com',  # Use your school's verified email address
            Destination={'ToAddresses': recipients},
            Message={
                'Subject': {'Data': subject},
                'Body': {'Text': {'Data': message}},
            },
            Attachments=[
                {
                    'FileName': f"{message['subject']}_{message['class_section']}_assignment.pdf",
                    'Data': s3.get_object(Bucket=message['bucket'], Key=message['key'])['Body'].read()
                }
            ]
        )
        print(f"Sent email to {', '.join(recipients)}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error sending email: {str(e)}")

def get_subject_teacher_email(subject):
    # Implement logic to dynamically determine the teacher's email based on the subject
    # You might use a mapping table, database, or another method
    # Example:
    if subject == 'Maths':
        return 'maths@xyz.com'
    elif subject == 'Science':
        return 'science@xyz.com'
    elif subject == 'Hindi':  # Add 'Hindi' subject mapping
        return 'hindi@xyz.com'
    # Add more subjects and email mappings as needed
```

to send email to multiple people i have stored the email list of all people on a different bucket lets its name is 'emaillistbucket' in which all emails are stored in 'email_mapping.json file.

Please tell me the troubleshooting steps for these two errors as I have tried a lot but unable to rectify these two errors. I am new to python and wrote this code with the help of my teammates and internet.If someone know the exact troubleshooting steps then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many times while using `s3_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']` operation it gives Key as URL type instead try

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse   
s3_key = urlparse(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])
```

Comment: They're not URLs. They're URL-encoded strings. That's a different thing. The code needs to [decode the key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64426932/271415).